# Scrapy-Selenium NYTimes issue

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scrapy

I've stuck trying to parse NYTimes page using Scrapy-Selenium. Link to the page: https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/21/travel/what-to-do-in-hoi-an-vietnam.html

As I can understand, it's a javascript driven page. When I disable javascript with help of a Chrome browser extension I see grey placeholders instead of some photographs.

Javascript enabled
[image: Javascript enabled]
Javascript disabled
[image: Javascript disabled]

The following snippet is this image with enabled JS:

```
<div data-testid="lazyimage-container" style="height: auto; cursor: pointer;">
<img alt="" class="css-1h6w7uo e1t57l6r0" src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/21/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An1/merlin_151549596_96de6b6d-174d-4cdb-add2-b77b5612ffab-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&amp;auto=webp&amp;disable=upscale" srcset="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/21/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An1/merlin_151549596_96de6b6d-174d-4cdb-add2-b77b5612ffab-articleLarge.jpg?quality=90&amp;auto=webp 600w,https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/21/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An1/merlin_151549596_96de6b6d-174d-4cdb-add2-b77b5612ffab-jumbo.jpg?quality=90&amp;auto=webp 1024w,https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/21/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An1/merlin_151549596_96de6b6d-174d-4cdb-add2-b77b5612ffab-superJumbo.jpg?quality=90&amp;auto=webp 2048w" sizes="((min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1004px)) 84vw, (min-width: 1005px) 80vw, 100vw" itemprop="url" itemid="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/21/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An1/merlin_151549596_96de6b6d-174d-4cdb-add2-b77b5612ffab-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&amp;auto=webp&amp;disable=upscale" style="opacity: 1;">
</div>
```

Without JS there's just div:

```
<div data-testid="lazyimage-container" style="height:257.77777777777777px"></div>
```

My Scrapy spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest


from pprint import pprint

class NytimesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nyt"

    start_urls = ["https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/21/travel/what-to-do-in-hoi-an-vietnam.html"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SeleniumRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse_result)

    def parse_result(self, response):
        print("=" * 60)
        imgs = response.css("img::attr(src)").getall()
        for img in imgs:
            print(img)
            print("")
        print("=" * 60)
```

The output:

```
============================================================
https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/24/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An6/merlin_151545219_ba2c9daa-c40a-4d52-80fe-ba679f3a98c2-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale

https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/24/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An6/merlin_151545219_ba2c9daa-c40a-4d52-80fe-ba679f3a98c2-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale

https://static01.nyt.com/images/2018/02/25/travel/25vietnam1/merlin_133277466_698b9b08-f2d5-43c4-a44e-978ddc23cbac-videoLarge.jpg

https://static01.nyt.com/images/2018/12/26/travel/26PTG-LAOS-COMBO-promo/26PTG-LAOS-COMBO-promo-threeByTwoSmallAt2X-v6.jpg

https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/21/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An2/merlin_151543719_ee268c49-2cac-47a6-855c-dedcb8fc7676-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale

https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/01/07/travel/52-PROMO/52-PROMO-articleLarge.jpg

https://mwcm.nyt.com/dam/mkt_assets/exo/img/nyt-logo-379x64.svg

https://et.nytimes.com/pixel?url=https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/21/travel/what-to-do-in-hoi-an-vietnam.html&referrer=&subject=module-interactions&moduleData=%7B%22module%22%3A%22nyt-vi-page-pixel%22%2C%22pgType%22%3A%22%22%2C%22eventName%22%3A%22Impression%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22Impression%22%7D&sourceApp=nyt-vi&instant=1&_=1553234896724

https://et.nytimes.com/pixel.gif?subject=ab-expose&test=PER_MoreIn_World&variant=3_au_most_popular&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F2019%2F03%2F21%2Ftravel%2Fwhat-to-do-in-hoi-an-vietnam.html&instant=1&skipAugment=true&gtm=GTM-P528B3-284-Production&et2_pageview_id=yrkmw_cn5c1oW40tVV_VdoTl

============================================================
```

The problem is that there's no required picture in the result list. The photo src is https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/21/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An1/merlin_151549596_96de6b6d-174d-4cdb-add2-b77b5612ffab-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale

The whole command line log is:

```
(nlp2) D:\Python\_Project\Scraping_train_data\snyt>scrapy crawl nyt
2019-03-22 09:08:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.2 started (bot: snyt)
2019-03-22 09:08:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.2.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 21 2019, 17:35:59) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019), cryptography 2.5, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
2019-03-22 09:08:11 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'snyt', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'snyt.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['snyt.spiders']}
2019-03-22 09:08:11 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 4d9b971e8de9258e
2019-03-22 09:08:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-03-22 09:08:14 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:56203/session {"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{}], "alwaysMatch": {"browserName": "firefox", "acceptInsecureCerts": true, "moz:firefoxOptions": {"args": ["--headless"]}}}, "desiredCapabilities": {"browserName": "firefox", "acceptInsecureCerts": true, "marionette": true, "moz:firefoxOptions": {"args": ["--headless"]}}}
2019-03-22 09:08:14 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1:56203
2019-03-22 09:08:16 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1:56203 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 200 702
2019-03-22 09:08:16 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2019-03-22 09:08:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-03-22 09:08:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-03-22 09:08:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-03-22 09:08:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-03-22 09:08:16 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-03-22 09:08:16 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-03-22 09:08:16 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:56203/session/fa7fe711-db01-4b58-8d86-2efd31b23529/url {"url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/21/travel/what-to-do-in-hoi-an-vietnam.html"}
2019-03-22 09:08:24 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1:56203 "POST /session/fa7fe711-db01-4b58-8d86-2efd31b23529/url HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2019-03-22 09:08:24 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2019-03-22 09:08:24 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:56203/session/fa7fe711-db01-4b58-8d86-2efd31b23529/source {}
2019-03-22 09:08:24 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1:56203 "GET /session/fa7fe711-db01-4b58-8d86-2efd31b23529/source HTTP/1.1" 200 1971834
2019-03-22 09:08:24 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2019-03-22 09:08:24 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:56203/session/fa7fe711-db01-4b58-8d86-2efd31b23529/url {}
2019-03-22 09:08:24 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1:56203 "GET /session/fa7fe711-db01-4b58-8d86-2efd31b23529/url HTTP/1.1" 200 87
2019-03-22 09:08:24 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2019-03-22 09:08:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/21/travel/what-to-do-in-hoi-an-vietnam.html> (referer: None)
============================================================
https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/24/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An6/merlin_151545219_ba2c9daa-c40a-4d52-80fe-ba679f3a98c2-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale

https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/24/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An6/merlin_151545219_ba2c9daa-c40a-4d52-80fe-ba679f3a98c2-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale

https://static01.nyt.com/images/2018/02/25/travel/25vietnam1/merlin_133277466_698b9b08-f2d5-43c4-a44e-978ddc23cbac-videoLarge.jpg

https://static01.nyt.com/images/2018/12/26/travel/26PTG-LAOS-COMBO-promo/26PTG-LAOS-COMBO-promo-threeByTwoSmallAt2X-v6.jpg

https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/21/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An2/merlin_151543719_ee268c49-2cac-47a6-855c-dedcb8fc7676-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale

https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/01/07/travel/52-PROMO/52-PROMO-articleLarge.jpg

https://mwcm.nyt.com/dam/mkt_assets/exo/img/nyt-logo-379x64.svg

https://et.nytimes.com/pixel?url=https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/21/travel/what-to-do-in-hoi-an-vietnam.html&referrer=&subject=module-interactions&moduleData=%7B%22module%22%3A%22nyt-vi-page-pixel%22%2C%22pgType%22%3A%22%22%2C%22eventName%22%3A%22Impression%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22Impression%22%7D&sourceApp=nyt-vi&instant=1&_=1553234896724

https://et.nytimes.com/pixel.gif?subject=ab-expose&test=PER_MoreIn_World&variant=3_au_most_popular&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F2019%2F03%2F21%2Ftravel%2Fwhat-to-do-in-hoi-an-vietnam.html&instant=1&skipAugment=true&gtm=GTM-P528B3-284-Production&et2_pageview_id=yrkmw_cn5c1oW40tVV_VdoTl

============================================================
2019-03-22 09:08:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-03-22 09:08:25 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: DELETE http://127.0.0.1:56203/session/fa7fe711-db01-4b58-8d86-2efd31b23529 {}
2019-03-22 09:08:26 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1:56203 "DELETE /session/fa7fe711-db01-4b58-8d86-2efd31b23529 HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2019-03-22 09:08:26 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2019-03-22 09:08:26 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/response_bytes': 1915145,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 22, 6, 8, 25, 30708),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 18,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 22, 6, 8, 16, 33466)}
2019-03-22 09:08:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I added these lines to settings.py accordingly to the instruction (https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium):

```
from shutil import which

SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'firefox'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('geckodriver')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['--headless']  

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}
```

I'm new to scraping javascript based sites but I've successfully parsed https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=war page with Scrapy-Selenium. Probably, Scrapy project settings are right.

Where is my mistake, why doesn't the spider see all the pictures?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: @DebanjanB, thank you. My question is why doesn't the spider see all the pictures, in particular the one I took a screenshot?

Comment: I don't do _scrapy_ but I think you are on spot when you mentioned _Javascript disabled_, those images are rendered through _lazy loading_ so without _JS_ even I don't expect _scrapy_ to collect them either.

Comment: @DebanjanB, I thought that Scrapy supported by Selenium has to see a page exactly as a user sees it. Doesn't it concern image lazy loading?

Comment: As I mentioned I don't do _Scrapy_ else I would have constructed an answer for your question :)

Comment: @DebanjanB, thank you for the hint :) you're a specialist in Selenium - can it do the trick in some way without Scrapy?

Comment: You seem to have got all the `src` as per the output under the **The output** section. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: @DebanjanB, I'v tried several codes, tried extracting text and html for img, outer div, both xpath and css selectors and always got an empty result for this particular picture. Here, I used extracting all images through the document in order to exclude any possible error (as it seems to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photos you need are `figure` tags with `aria-label="media"` attribute. You can get image links using the selector and get `itemid` attribute, which contains url of the image.

Here is HTML:

```
<figure class="css-kyszhr e1g7ppur0" aria-label="media" role="group"
        itemProp="associatedMedia" itemscope=""
        itemID="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/03/21/travel/21Hours-Hoi-An5/merlin_151541649_b7b94eb2-7166-4849-ba4e-a93343607370-articleLarge.jpg?quality=90&amp;auto=webp"
        itemType="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <div class="css-1xdhyk6 erfvjey0"><span class="css-1ly73wi e1tej78p0">Image</span>
        <div class="css-zjzyr8">
            <div data-testid="lazyimage-container"
                 style="height:257.77777777777777px"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <figcaption itemProp="caption description" class="css-1l6g02d e1xdpqjp0"><span
            class="css-8i9d0s e13ogyst0">Tadioto, an elegant new whisky bar in the French Quarter, is hidden behind a clothing boutique.</span><span
            itemProp="copyrightHolder" class="css-vuqh7u e1z0qqy90"><span
            class="css-1ly73wi e1tej78p0">Credit</span><span>Justin Mott for The New York Times</span></span>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

You can also try to use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to scrape:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.nytimes.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36',
    'dnt': '1',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,'
              'application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/21/travel/what-to-do-in-hoi-an-vietnam.html', headers=headers)

page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

figures = page.find_all("figure", {"aria-label": "media"})
for figure in figures:
    print(figure.attrs["itemid"])

images = page.find_all("img")
for image in images:
    print(image.attrs["src"])

print("the end")
```

Comment: Sers, you're a genius! Thank you very much. I've never coded a website and don't know so kind of features. You opened my eyes